# How to access data from Google Data Store Using Anguarjs $Http POST Request?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-datastore

**I have Tried and below is my code i don't know what went wrong**

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  headers:'{"gqlQuery": {"queryString": "select * from culture" }}',
  url: 'https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nammaooru-3630e:runQuery?fields=batch%2Cquery&key=[myapikey]'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

  alert("Success"+response);
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("Error"+response);
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Got Error in angular Request**

> [https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nammaooru-3630e:runQuery?fields=batch%2Cquery&key=[apikey]](https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nammaooru-3630e:runQuery?fields=batch%2Cquery&key=%5Bapikey%5D)
>
> ```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
> ```

**Got Error while trying in Postman**

```
URL : https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nammaooru-3630e:runQuery?fields=batch%2Cquery&key=[apikey]

Method : POST 


    {
      "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
      }
    }
```

**But I got out put response from Google Developer site**

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#http-request

```
{
 "batch": {
  "entityResultType": "FULL",
  "entityResults": [
   {
    "entity": {
     "key": {
      "partitionId": {
       "projectId": "nammaooru-3630e"
      },
      "path": [
       {
        "kind": "culture",
        "id": "5629499534213120"
       }
      ]
     },
     "properties": {
      "types": {
       "stringValue": "",
       "excludeFromIndexes": true
      },
      "images": {
       "stringValue": "",
       "excludeFromIndexes": true
      },
      "bname": {
       "stringValue": "Kangeyam Kalai"
      },
      "date": {
       "timestampValue": "2017-01-14T12:44:56.933Z"
      },
      "title": {
       "stringValue": ""
      },
      "description": {
       "stringValue": "Coimbatore Kongu nadu region",
       "excludeFromIndexes": true
      }
     }
    },
    "cursor": "Ci8SKWoRc35uYW1tYW9vcnUtMzYzMGVyFAsSB2N1bHR1cmUYgICAgICAgAoMGAAgAA==",
    "version": "1484398012256000"
   }
  ],
  "endCursor": "Ci8SKWoRc35uYW1tYW9vcnUtMzYzMGVyFAsSB2N1bHR1cmUYgICAgICAgAoMGAAgAA==",
  "moreResults": "NO_MORE_RESULTS"
 },
 "query": {
  "kind": [
   {
    "name": "culture"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to configure your remote access in your google account?

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin may be of help

Comment: How can i do that is there any example available ?

Comment: Sorry was updating my comment :)

Comment: Thanks i need some time to read ... Dale :)

Comment: That's interesting, do you have any Chrome extensions enabled that could be messing up with the CORS headers? There are a few out there that add arbitrary headers. I don't see how a Google API would add http://evil.com unless that was your true origin.

CORS only allows a single origin for Access-Control-Allow-Origin or a wildcard operator. https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

Comment: evil.com is usually added by Chrome extensions added for disabling CORS.

Comment: There's a nice chrome plugin for disabling CORS. I use it a lot when I develop a front end and a back end, but don't have them running on the same port. Out of curiosity, if there's a datastore instance, is there a GAE project related to it? If so, any reason you wouldn't just upload a little Python or Java, hit an endpoint, and use the datastore API? I used to mess around with hitting the DS directly from JS but in the end abandoned it, too many issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an angularjs user, but looking at the error I am guessing that you haven't done authentication.
Google is using OAuth 2.0 for authentication, you can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent)

Basically you need to request authentication token and then you use acquired token in your api calls. (thats the header bit you are missing, **Authorization: Bearer yourtokenhere**)

Answer (score 1):

--disable-web-security and restart the chrome by run below command in window "Run":

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Comment: that dsn work , i think something need to be changed in forming headers

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is CORS related issue. Do you have access from POSTMAN?

Another thing, your query string from headers, should be in request body.

Comment: body:'{"gqlQuery": {"queryString": "select * from culture" }}', ?? I this right?

Comment: even I have tried in my device ... it is not cors issue i hope

Comment: try with POSTMAN extension for chrome first. according to docs:{
  "partitionId": {
    object(PartitionId)
  },
  "readOptions": {
    object(ReadOptions)
  },

  // Union field query_type can be only one of the following:
  "query": {
    object(Query)
  },
  "gqlQuery": {
    object(GqlQuery)
  },
  // End of list of possible types for union field query_type.
}

Comment: it should work with {"gqlQuery": {"queryString": "select * from culture" }} I got error 401 UNAUTHENTICATED, "The request does not have valid authentication credentials. You have to add OATH authorization